# Automating ArcMap quantile plotting with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, classification, graph, error-000728

I have a shapefile to which a CSV file with multiple columns has been joined. This CSV file has numeric values ranging from 0 to 1800. After joining, I have to plot each column as each plot (or data frame or map, I don't know what to call it) in ArcMap using Quantile classification. This means that if I have 6 columns in the joined CSV file, then I am expecting 6 plots in series with quantile classification. Until now, I am able to join the CSV file to layer in one data frame and saved it as a layer file. Then, added that layer file to all dataframes. Further, I have to classify each data frame using Quantile classification and export them as an image.

```py
#importing the necessary packages
import arcpy

#Defining Environment in ArcMap and importing the mxd file into ArcMap
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\\Users\\Jaggu\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\Project\CROPWAT\WRR\DistrictScaleNew1\Block_scale\ArcMap\IWR.mxd")
lyrfile = r'D:\Project\CROPWAT\WRR\DistrictScaleNew1\Block_scale\ArcMap\AP_APWRIMS.lyr'
lyrfile1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrfile) #Converting to a layer file in the current env
shpfile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'D:\IND_adm\AP_APWRIMS.shp')

#Arcpy cannot create new data frames, so I created empty data frames manually.
#It is a bug in ArcMap #https://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4ODQ2Ng==
#Then symbology was changed in each data frame through a for loop.
dfs = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
currentfield = 'Groundnut'
csvfields = ['Jowar', 'Paddy', 'Redgram', 'Sugarcane']
for df in dfs:
    #updatelyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "AP_APWRIMS", df)[0]
    #arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,shpfile)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,lyrfile1,"BOTTOM")
    currentlayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)[0]
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(currentlayer)
    currentlayerfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(currentlayer)]
    currentfield = currentlayerfields[14]
    for field in currentlayerfields[15:]:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(currentlayer, currentfield, field, "PYTHON")
        if lyrfile1.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_SYMBOLS":
            currentlayer.symbology.classBreakValues = range(0,2100,300) #IWR interval definition
mxd.saveACopy(r'D:\Project\CROPWAT\WRR\DistrictScaleNew1\Block_scale\ArcMap\AP_APWRIMS1.mxd')
#print(len(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)))
```

I believe that my error is somewhere in the 'calculate field management'. What exactly I want to achieve is that the current field has to be replaced with another field and resymbolize the plots. Can I do that?

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\CROPWAT\WRR\DistrictScaleNew1\Block_scale\ArcMap\PlottingScript.py", line 26, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(currentlayer, currentfield, field, "PYTHON")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3663, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000728: Field AP_IWR.csv.Groundnut does not exist within table
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Comment: You ***really*** want to avoid joining to an ASCII file, since they can't be indexed. Instead, load it into a file geodatabase table, index the join field, and *then try your calculation.  Please [Edit] the question to specify the datatype of the join column.

Comment: My datatype in the joined file is numeric. I have updated that in the question. And, what do you mean by joining an ASCII file? I am new to ArcPy, so could you please elaborate on it further?

Comment: CSV is an ASCII format (variable width characters). Integer joins are fine, but floating-point joins ***never*** work reliably (ASCII representation is incompatible with binary IEEE float). You also have what seems to be a random deprecated SearchCursor fragment in your code as well. If you have an error, you should provide that, as text, in the body of the question.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problems with joining the CSV file. I have updated my question and inserted the error that I am getting. Right now, I am trying to convert CSV to geodatabase format and then try to perform the calculation. And BTW, I have the SearchCursor fragment above the ListFields command because the ListFields command is not working without the SearchCursor fragment. I don't know why.

Comment: Well, I tried with the geodatabase file, and the same error pops up. Any help? The error that the field does not exist within table. It is as follows: ```ExecuteError: ERROR 000728: Field IWR.Groundnut does not exist within table
Failed to execute (CalculateField).```

Comment: Impossible to debug this without the data. Which line is causing the error